# How does a convex lens produce an image at a distance?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

[image]

What exactly is going on in this ray diagram? If the object AB is placed between the focal point and center of the lens, then how does the image A'B' form at a distance? Where is the light being reflected from? Where even are these rays converging to form an image?

Comment: Hi. Have you learnt about virtual images?

Answer (score 0):

Light follows the path traced by the solid line. So the light is not reflected. However what you can see is that the two lines actually started from the same point (on the object), but after passing the lens has refracted away from each other. Now what the dashed line is representing is if you trace back the refracted ray, where will they meet? Since the rays started out from the same point on the object, the point where the traced lines intersect will be the place where the image will be formed. What an image represents is where and how the object will seem to be for a person looking through the other side of the lens.

The example you’ve shown is basically how a magnifying lens works. We are using lens to magnify objects on the other side of the lens.

Comment: Notice that the object at AB and the virtual image at A'B' (which can be seen by an eye looking through the lens but will not appear on a screen) have about the same angular size.  The observed increase in angular size results from bringing the object closer to the lens (and eye) and inside your near pint.